# Laravel undefine variable in view

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm new to laravel. Using version 5.4 and tried to search but don't see what I'm doing wrong. I keep getting an "Undefined variable: post" in my view. I'm also doing form model binding. Model binding works properly when manually entering URL. Just can't click on link to bring up edit view.

My routes:

```
Route::get('test/{id}/edit','TestController@edit');
```

My controller:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);

    if(!$post)
        abort(404);
    return view('test/edit')->with('test', $post);
}
```

My form:

```
{{  Form::model($post, array('route' => array('test.update', $post->id), 'files' => true, 'method' => 'PUT')) }}
```

Comment: You are returning the content of `$post` as `'test'` - So you can access this variable in your view in this case with `$test` instead `$post`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller is sending a variable named "test", but your error says that your blade file doesn't have the `$post` variable passed into it. This can be fixed by changing "test" to "post" in your controller.

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning the post value to 'test', so should be accessible with `$test` rather than `$post`.

You probably want to do either of these two things instead:

```
return view('test/edit')->with('post', $post);
```

or

```
return view('test/edit', ['post' => $post]);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views